# Why EncdDecd.EncodeStream is returning a new line?

Tags: delphi, encoding, base64

I'm using the function `EncodeStream` (from `EncdDecd.pas`) in order to convert an array of bytes into a base64 string but I'm obtaining a string which contains a newline.

This is the conversion function I'm using:

```
uses
  EncdDecd, ...;

function EncodeBase64(AValue : TBytes) : string;
var
  StreamDecoded : TMemoryStream;
  StreamEncoded : TStringStream;
begin
  StreamDecoded := TMemoryStream.Create;
  StreamEncoded := TStringStream.Create('');
  try
    StreamDecoded.WriteBuffer(AValue[0], Length(AValue));
    StreamDecoded.Position := 0;
    EncdDecd.EncodeStream(StreamDecoded, StreamEncoded);
    Result := StreamEncoded.DataString;
  finally
    StreamEncoded.Free;
    StreamDecoded.Free;
  end;
end;
```

And this is a simple test which causes a new line appears in the string resulted from `EncodeBase64` function:

```
var
  Bts : TBytes;
begin
  SetLength(Bts, 64);

  Bts[0] := 241;
  Bts[1] := 96;
  Bts[2] := 227;
  Bts[3] := 47;
  Bts[4] := 91;
  Bts[5] := 80;
  Bts[6] := 83;
  Bts[7] := 14;
  Bts[8] := 103;
  Bts[9] := 54;
  Bts[10] := 95;
  Bts[11] := 212;
  Bts[12] := 116;
  Bts[13] := 91;
  Bts[14] := 149;
  Bts[15] := 179;
  Bts[16] := 34;
  Bts[17] := 104;
  Bts[18] := 175;
  Bts[19] := 54;
  Bts[20] := 187;
  Bts[21] := 208;
  Bts[22] := 2;
  Bts[23] := 76;
  Bts[24] := 110;
  Bts[25] := 187;
  Bts[26] := 32;
  Bts[27] := 226;
  Bts[28] := 138;
  Bts[29] := 217;
  Bts[30] := 8;
  Bts[31] := 42;
  Bts[32] := 8;
  Bts[33] := 128;
  Bts[34] := 245;
  Bts[35] := 79;
  Bts[36] := 63;
  Bts[37] := 140;
  Bts[38] := 48;
  Bts[39] := 74;
  Bts[40] := 83;
  Bts[41] := 114;
  Bts[42] := 73;
  Bts[43] := 16;
  Bts[44] := 97;
  Bts[45] := 151;
  Bts[46] := 138;
  Bts[47] := 239;
  Bts[48] := 12;
  Bts[49] := 164;
  Bts[50] := 170;
  Bts[51] := 114;
  Bts[52] := 170;
  Bts[53] := 12;
  Bts[54] := 241;
  Bts[55] := 136;
  Bts[56] := 105;
  Bts[57] := 247;
  Bts[58] := 2;
  Bts[59] := 30;
  Bts[60] := 125;
  Bts[61] := 21;
  Bts[62] := 245;
  Bts[63] := 102;

  ShowMessage(EncodeBase64(Bts));
end;
```

`ShowMessage` method displays the following result:

> 8WDjL1tQUw5nNl/UdFuVsyJorza70AJMbrsg4orZCCoIgPVPP4wwSlNySRBhl4rvDKSqcqoM8Yhp
>   9wIefRX1Zg==

In the real scenario, I'm writing this string as value of an attribute of an ini file and the new line causes a part of the string is lost when reading it back from the ini file (`TIniFile.ReadString` reads only the first line).

Could someone help me understanding why the new line appear and how should I manage such strings when writing an ini file?

**Note:**

I'm testing on Delphi2007.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [line feed in base64](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4648#section-3.1) is discussed in [RFC 4648](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4648).

> MIME is often used as a reference for base 64 encoding.  However,
> MIME does not define "base 64" per se, but rather a "base 64
> Content-Transfer-Encoding" for use within MIME.  As such, MIME
> enforces a   limit on line length of base 64-encoded data to 76
> characters.  MIME   inherits the encoding from Privacy Enhanced Mail
> (PEM), stating   that it is "virtually identical"; however, PEM
> uses a line length of   64 characters.  The MIME and PEM limits are
> both due to limits within   SMTP.
>
> Implementations MUST NOT add line feeds to base-encoded data unless
> the specification referring to this document explicitly directs base
> encoders to add line feeds after a specific number of characters.

The encoder that you are using was written with MIME in mind and enforces line feeds every 76 characters.

Modern versions of Delphi have introduced the `System.NetEncoding` unit which now contains the RTL implementation of base64. And the functionality in `System.NetEncoding` now allows you to suppress line feeds in encoded content.

You have a couple of options, as I see it:

1. Remove the line feeds after encoding.
2. Use a different base64 encoder that does not insert line feeds.

Comment: You've clarified all doubts about that, thank you. As you suggested, I think I'll remove line feeds after encoding until I'll upgrade my Delphi IDE.